# Where can I find the episodes to the Black Panther 2010 Animated series?

Tags: marvel, tv, black-panther

I saw that there is an animated series of Black Panther available on YouTube and it says animated series 2010.

So I thought I would get all the series and episodes, but I could only find 5 episodes of the first season?

Any idea where I could get all the episodes of the Black Panther animated series that aired in 2010?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because shopping questions are off-topic

Comment: @Valorum I thought shopping _recommendations_ should be closed, not "does this exist"-questions such as this one.

Comment: Questions about where to buy things *that are trivially simple to find* are off-topic. The allowance is "*i've looked everywhere and I still can't find it"* along with some evidence of searching. Even a tiny modicum of research would have given OP their answer.

Answer (score 2):

All the episodes are available for free on Marvel's official YouTube channel.

Here's the link to the playlist: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLK5HARgNfgj_FRfxSYUSQiAE_vC5fYPcw

Comment: That's only half the episodes. There are 12 episodes in total, as seen [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100621012304/http://www.craveonline.com/entertainment/comics/article/marvel-comics-reveals-black-panther-animated-series-104879). Strange that then on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Panther_(TV_series)) it says only 6 episodes were released.

Comment: 6 episodes, surely; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Panther_(TV_series)?

Comment: Okay, my bad. I went by the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Panther_(TV_series)) that says 6 episodes.

Comment: They appear to be split into two; https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1441105/episodes?season=1&ref_=tt_eps_sn_1

Comment: Yep. Each episode on YouTube is ~20 minutes long but according to the IMDB entries, they are ~10 minutes long. So it's the same 6 episodes split into 12.

Comment: Only 6 episodes as on youtube?, Sad as i was hoping for some more episodes as i have already completed the first 6 episodes.

Comment: Also a bit strange that since 2010, only 6 episofe

Comment: It probably wasn't popular.